# your cpu does not support NX

Tags: android, android-studio

i just downloaded the android studio but i have a problem .when i run it says your cpu does not support NX. what should i do ?

Answer (score 11):

NX or actually "NX processor bit" is a feature of a processor that helps to protect your PC from attacks by malicious software. When this feature is not enabled and you try to run certain emulators in android studio, you will get an error message like this (second line: "You CPU does not support NX."):

[image: Error message]

To check whether NX is enabled on your processor you can use the command line tool "coreinfo" (available here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722)

[image: coreinfo command line tool]

If you can see a dash next to "NX" it means it is disabled. If that is the case, check whether your CPU even supports the NX processor bit. In the example above I am using a i7-2600K CPU. According to this (http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_i7/Intel-Core%20i7-2600K%20CM8062300833908.html) list on cpu-world it should be supported.

Since it is supported but shown as disabled in "coreinfo", it has probably been disabled in BIOS. So go to your BIOS settings and make sure to enable it there:

[image: BIOS NX setting]

Once you have done this, you can check "coreinfo" again to see whether it has been successfully enabled:

[image: coreinfo with NX enabled]

Note that now there is an asterisk (*) next to "NX", which means it has been successfully enabled. You should now no longer receive the error message in Android Studio.

PS: In our example the Intel HAXM was also missing, which is why the error message shown at the top was bigger. This issue can be resolved by downloading the corresponding software (here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager)

Comment: Nice answer. I knew VT can be disabled in BIOS (and also knew it's enabled on my PC), but did not know NX can be disabled as well.