# HAXM is required to run this AVD

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have created emulator in android studio and create little application in it. When i run it gives me an error[See image 1]. When i googled, it told me that your system does not support virtualization. But my system suport it. [See image 2].

Now my question is that when my system support virtualization then why i cannot run my app in emulator. Also please help on this following error too.

1-Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.

2-Your CPU does not support NX.

Please anyone help to resolve this issues, thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is VT-X enabled in BIOS?

Comment: Yes virtualiazatuon is enabled in bios. What's next?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried to install haxm after download from internet. When i run it gives me an error: The computer does not support intel excute disable bit(XD). And second error when running android studio: Your CPU does not support NX. What may be cause of this issue?. Is my system support to all these things or i have to buy new latest model laptop ?

Comment: Do as I said in my answer, but instead of looking for `NX`, look for `XD`.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @AbAppletic XN options is not available in my laptop while virtualization is enabled in bios. I am still unable to install android studio completely because of XN.

Comment: If your CPU doesn't support NX, then you cannot use the Emulaotr

Comment: Why can't you install AS? Do you get an error about NX missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Source of answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36885582/5889375)*)
First off, download [Coreinfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722), extract the zip in your Downloads folder, then run CMD (Not as admin), and type in:

```
cd Downloads
cd Coreinfo
coreinfo
```

Then, you should get a list of text. Scroll up/down until you find **NX**. If there's `-` next to `NX`, then it isn't enabled or it isn't supported. If there's `*` and you still get the error, then you're doing something else wrong.
[image]

Then, check if NX and VT-x are enabled in BIOS:

[image]

If not, enable it. If you don't see an option, then your CPU doesn't support `NX`.

After you enable it, do the first step again. You should now see `*`, which means NX is enabled:

[image]