# Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD error in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intel, android-virtual-device, haxm

I followed the steps in  this link: [Solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39304849/haxm-is-required-to-run-this-avd)

1st step: Checked BIOS and enabled the virtualization capability.
2nd step: Installed the Intel HAXM installer.
3rd step: Checked android studio and see if the problem is solved, it is not solved.

I checked youtube and google searches and I've done most of them. In coreinfo, my NX has an asterisk sign meaning the it is enabled already and I haven't done anything wrong in my bios setup.

EDIT: PC Specs
Windows 7
Intel Core i3 2120
4GB RAM
Asus H61M-E

Comment: pc configuration

Comment: @VineshChauhan where exactly? i've been to bios settings and my virtualization capability is already enabled, if that's what you mean.

Comment: have you tried to install haxm from https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm

Comment: @VineshChauhan Yes I already did.

Comment: What is your pc configuration?

Comment: @VineshChauhan Windows 7
Intel Core i3 2120
4GB RAM
Asus H61M-E

Comment: @user6019827 Windows 7
Intel Core i3 2120
4GB RAM
Asus H61M-E